# View is moving down in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, autoresize

I am using slide out navigation in my app. In that some pages view slide down automatically sometimes. In simulator it is in perfect position while in some device it looks perfect and in some it slide down. Here is screen shots:
1)Simulator screen shot(should look like):
[image]

2)device screen shot:

[image]

You can see by back whit sun that view is moving down. I have set that image as background color of view. There something auto-resizing property which I have to set but I tried many thing but same result can any one tell me why exactly this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your simulator is set to the same device hardware as of your physical device?

Comment: We'll need a code sample or a more detailed description in order to help.

Comment: @SarimSidd yes both are same. And I got same thing simulator when I wrote self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;

Comment: @Brandon..See my comments.

Comment: @vivek - Check autolayout is turned off - set your views according to this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804022/ios-7-navigation-bar-and-scroll-view-are-different-in-storyboard-and-simulator/21829917#21829917 and try this one as well - set frames UIcontrols which scrolls downwards

Answer (score 0):

i think auto-resizing is right option to display uiview correctly on device try out one of following property which might help

these are the available option for ios 7 for resizing uiview 
you can add add just one line of code to correct this

view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

or

view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

Comment: can you explain me what will this code do exactly ??

Comment: is it  compulsory to write self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone in ios 7 . Because this happen to me when I wrote that line. Should I place all component after setting this line?

Comment: It is the purpose of edgesForExtendedLaoyout which was set to UIRectEdgeNone to not extend the view in any direction, but your view will now start in origin within the screen size (now below the statusBar!) when using a frame with position of 0, 0 (like you did with the customControl). You need to adjust the frame of your view/viewController to represent that you want to start under the statusBar/navigationBar or make the status/nagivationBar opaque; or add UIRectEdgeTop if only used for one view.